# Is it possible to use OR condition with an IF rule and changes rule in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to specificy an `if` rule and `changes` rule in gitlab CI together with an OR condition?

For example when I have these rules:

```
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
    - changes:
      - 'src/*'
```

The job is trigger when both are true -> the branch is not `main` and there are changes in `src`. Howeven I want the job to be triggered when the branch is not `main` or when there are changes in the `src` folder.

In my example I have tests running in the pipeline of the merge request. So when I do not have any functional changes there is no point in running tests. Also, when the pipeline is for the main branch the tests have already been ran on the MR pipeline so I don't want to run them again.

Comment: It works like an OR how u have specified it ie. it will run when Commits are added to branch other than main or when there is a change in src/

Comment: Is it possible to change it to AND instead of OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have specified it will work as an `OR`. To make it an `AND` ie.
to run it when the branch is not main and there are changes to src folder

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
      changes:
        - 'src/*'
```